Classical FeH8 or FeH10 at most?
Fe has 8 valence electrons. Can it bind theoretically 10 H atoms to form classical FeH10 molecule with 18 electrons on Fe and normal single bonds? Or is the FeH8 the highest possible  molecular hydride form of Fe? Non-classical FeH2(H2)4, the high hydrogen-content anions as well as solid, high-pressure Superhydrides are excluded from the inspection. Another example would be the ScH3 and ScH4 pair. And so on.

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Compounds between Iron and Hydrogen are not numerous. To my knowledge only $\ce{FeH}$ and $\ce{FeH2}$ do exist. But $\ce{FeH2}$ is only stable at the liquid air temperature.

@Maurice Polymeric iron hydride or polyhydride also exists. In the article, it also mentions that $\ce{FeH2}$ may form a dimer $\ce{Fe2H4}$ and complexes with molecular hydrogen, such as $\ce{FeH2(H2)2}$ and $\ce{FeH2(H2)3}$.

@Nilay Ghosh. You are right. Compounds with one $\ce{Fe}$ atom and several $\ce{H}$ atoms do exist at high pressures, and often as matrix. But at room temperature and pressure, they get decomposed.

We generally do not model bonding in transition metal complexes with pairwise electron sharing. Even where pairwise electronic interactions accurately count the valence electrons associated with the metal, an accurate descrption of the bonding requires assuming that the electrons are delocalized over the multiple metal-ligand linkages. You may start learning about ligand field theory in Wikipedia and the references cited in the article.
Also with $3d$-valence metals like iron, complexes with more than six ligands are rare due to steric limitations, even with the apparently small hydride ligand. To fully saturate the metal valence orbitals with hydride ligands we likely need to add electrons from ionic bonding with electropositive metals plus the hydride ligands. The best known example with iron is $\ce{(Mg^{2+})2(FeH6)^{4-}}$, a hydrogen-storage medium that can be synthesized using steel as the iron source [1].
Reference

Marek Polanski, Daria Nawra, Dariusz Zasada (2019). "Mg2FeH6 synthesized from plain steel and magnesium hydride". Journal of Alloys and Compounds, Volume 776, Pages 1029-1040,
ISSN 0925-8388,
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jallcom.2018.10.310.

